# Macbook pro latest retina: Output to monitor with VGA

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, hdmi, displayport

I bought a new latest Mac book pro Retina. I see in my mac book, there are two ports: one for thunderbolt and one for HDMI (or HDMI, I don't know).

I want to output to monitor with VGA display, so I need a converter. As I know, there are two type of converters as I research: HDMI to VGA and Mini DisplayPort to VGA. So I have many questions because I don't sure about those port:

1. Does my mac have Mini DisplayPort ? I see in this link: [Apple Support](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3382) says that Mini DisplayPort and thunderbolt is comparable, right? So I can use Mini DisplayPort to VGA adapter for thunderbolt port ?
2. Which adapter should I use for output to monitor. HDMI to VGA or Mini DisplayPort to VGA. If I can use both, which is better ?
3. Macbook pro ships with HDMI or mini HDMI. I guess HDMI but I'm not sure.

I'm sorry for those questions because my lack of hardware knowledge. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can connect the Thunderbolt port to a VGA adapter for your VGA monitor.
2. I'm pretty sure it does not matter. I'm not sure if a simple HDMI-to-VGA adapter even exists.
3. The Macbook Retina that I have has 2 thunderbolt ports and one normal-size HDMI port.

This MacRumors topic contains some useful info as well:
http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1426993

Comment: thanks for your link. that's help me. about (2), i'm pretty sure that HDMI-to-VGA exist, you can google it. after researching, I understand that thunderbolt can be used to transfer data/audio/video ... and connect to screen too. So, now, I don't know, which is better to use. Do you know ? Thanks :)

Comment: Your Macbook Pro Retina has 2 thunderbolt ports, so you can use 1 for your monitor and the other for possible data transfer using a thunderbolt connector cable.

About the adapter you're right: they are simple and cheap. :)

Speaking of cheap, and please excuse me if I've misread the situation, you are getting a Macbook Retina and still use a VGA monitor? Maybe you should consider getting a newer monitor with DVI to take advantage of your macbook's digital signal instead of converting it to analog VGA. Good luck!

Comment: @Sephia thanks for helping me. now i understand all now. about VGA Monitor, just because I bought it last 2 years and it shipped with my PC. Before that, I have never though about vga/dvi/thunderbolt ... just now. i need to transfer to lcd for easier to work. so maybe as you said, if image quanlity is slow. maybe i will change to more suitable monitor :D